# Connecting to MongoDB - error that it connects to the native driver port

Tags: mongodb, flask

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database by using Google Chrome (Windows) and using the flask module. When I go to the page: http://localhost:27017/OData/data I get the following error message:

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

The config file is as follows:

```
sqlconfig = {
  'host': '127.0.0.1',
  'port': '3306',
  'user': 'username',
  'passwd': 'password',
  'database': 'dwh',
  'charset': 'utf8mb4',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}
nosqlconfig = "mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dwh?authSource=admin"

baseurl = "link"
```

Should I change the port or something else?

Comment: You can't connect to mongo over http like that unless you start mongod like this: `mongod --httpinterface`

Comment: I tried the following, which gives an error message:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin>mongod --httpinterface
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--httpinterface'
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

Comment: sorry, the last version of mongo that has the httpinterface is 3.4. Anything after that will not work, because it was removed. You can try alternative http interfaces (there are a lot of open source projects that let you do this).

Comment: Why do you want to access MongoDB using your web browser?